# RaisePropertyChanged fails to update the UI

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light

I've been working on an application in *MVVM Light* lately. I have a *TextBox* in my *XAML* bound to my *UI*. I'd like to validate any input and ensure that only numbers are entered. I've tried the following code:

My *TextBox*:

```
<TextBox TabIndex="1" Height="23" MinWidth="410" DockPanel.Dock="Left" 
         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
         Text="{Binding Input, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
         IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}"
         AcceptsReturn="False"
         local:FocusExtension.IsFocused="{Binding IsFocused}">
```

And in my ViewModel:

```
private string input;
public string Input
{
    get { return this.input; }
    set
    {
        decimal test;
        if(decimal.TryParse(value, out test))
        {
            this.input = value;
        }
        else
        {
            this.input = "";
        }

        RaisePropertyChanged("Input");
    }
}
```

This fails to update the *UI*. If I enter *"B"* and check the debugger, it runs through the setter, but fails to actually update the *UI*.

Curiously, if I set `this.input = "TEST";` in the else block, the `UI` updates, but, if I attempt to set it to *""*, *string.Empty*, or the value of input before the validation, the *UI* fails to update.

Is this by design? Possibly a bug? Is there something I'm doing wrong?

**Edit** I mistakenly forgot to include `RaisePropertyChanged` in my example code. I've updated it. Raising it isn't the problem as I've watched the debugger run all the way through raising it and returning input via the getter.

Comment: You're not actually raising `OnPropertyChanged`. Does this class implement `IPropertyChanged`?

Comment: @neoistheone I'm raising `RaisePropertyChanged`. I mistakenly forgot to put that in the code in the question.

Comment: Has this been solved somehow? I am exactly in your situation and can confirm every point you make.

Answer (score 0):

Way you use strign type property and then convert to decimal, easier to change lik this:

```
public decimal Input
{
    get { return this.input; }
    set 
        { 
          this.input = value;
         RaisePropertyChanged("Input");
      } 
}
```

And for validate use IDataErrorInfo (read more: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2007/10/02/data-validation-in-3-5.aspx)

Comment: All good points, but 1. Fails to actually answer the question, and 2. That wouldn't show as empty which could be what the op is going for.

Comment: @StefanDenchev Like you said, I'd rather clear out the TextBox. This answer raises a lot of good points, but, ultimately, I can't change the binding to a decimal as I need to recycle it later for non-numeric input.

Answer (score 0):

What we have done is created a Custom Control, since we use it for a Currency Text Box. I warn you I have no validation that this is a good idea, or falls in line with MVVM model because all manipulation of the control are done in code behind.

In the control on the textbox we have an event on PreviewTextInput that does this

```
e.Handled = Functions.DoubleConverter(Convert.ToChar(e.Text), ((TextBox)sender).Text.Replace("$", ""));
```

Then for the function (which isnt perfect, I have a few issues with it still) is:

```
static public bool DoubleConverter(char c, string str)
{
    if (!char.IsDigit(c))
    {
        if (c == '.' && (str.Contains('.')))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (c != '.')
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Please use this as a reference, not exactly as is because it is a very crude implementation.

Comment: I fail to see how this answers why `RaisPropertyChanged()` won't update the UI in my setter. :c

Comment: Sorry, I spent days in the past trying to figure this one out, and never could, so this is the best I could come up with. Hopefully somebody knows why.